# How to use aliases in a way that works with both browserify and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, commonjs

We are working on a a codebase that needs to be able to both compile in browserify and run on nodejs. We will be loading specific javascript files in nodejs, and they need to be able to `require()` their dependencies.

We want to create a bunch of folder aliases like
`"models": "js/app/models/"`
so that when you `require("models/coolModel")` it is the same as saying `require("js/app/models/coolModel")`.

We tried using `aliasify` but that only works for browserify, and we looked at `node-alias` but that only works in the node environment.

Is there an approach that will work for both?

Answer (score 0):

Make an alias in  your file system between `models/coolModel` and `js/app/models/coolModel`

In unix it's a symlink and in windows it's a directory junction. Then you can refer to models/coolModel and still get the files you need in the other directory.

Comment: Eh, that could potentially work, but the nice thing about aliases is that I can say "models/" and regardless of where I am in my app, it will always go to the same folder. In this case, I'd need to do a relative URL to the symlink.